# How to clear hidden attribute from partition if "attributes volume clear hidden" fails with "Virtual Disk Service error: The object is not found."

Tags: windows, windows-8, partitioning, diskpart

After `select volume [n]` in `diskpart` `attributes volume clear hidden` fails with

```
Virtual Disk Service error:
The object is not found.
```

I found some forum threads which might contain a solution (http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/248241-repair-windows-7-boot-menu-uefi-4.html, https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cc44af84-f8f2-4fc2-8445-ad34d62ae8f2/problem-clear-hidden-volume-in-diskpart?forum=winservercore), but I can't figure it out *and* keep my sanity. The world is ready for Q&A quality answer.

I'm using Windows 8 on a Lenovo IdeaPad U410 in the recovery `cmd`. Windows doesn't boot after installing an Ubuntu dual boot. I just need to do a BIOS update (has to run on Windows) and don't care about Windows. I don't have any recovery media and the issue I'm trying to fix with the BIOS update is not worth buying one.

I can't remember if I every booted windows, I might have just moved initially installed partitions around with `gparted`. Removing the `hidden` flag with `gparted` on Ubuntu 16.04 causes the `hidden` flag to be removed across reboots, but still be displayed in `diskpart`.

The output of `attributes disk` after `select volume [n]` is

```
Current Read-only state: No
Read-only: No
Boot disk: No
Pagefile Disk: No
Hibernation File Disk: No
Crashdump Disk: No
Clustered Disk: No
```

`chkdsk [letter]: /f /r /x` passed for all 4 volumes and are reported `Healthy` in `diskpart`.

After `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot` which complete successfully `bootrec /scanos` find 0 Windows installations.

Comment: use a windows boot image and run the 
`bootrec.exe /fixmbr`
`bootrec.exe /fixboot`
`bootrec.exe /rebuildBCD`

Comment: `bootrec` commands run successfully, but `bootrec /scanos` indicates that there're 0 Windows installations as does `bootrec /rebuildBCD`.

Comment: I am out of ideas. Log in with a live cd, create backup of everything you need, than do a format / fresh install.

Comment: I don't have any (recovery or live) media than the HDDs in the device and don't want to by one (see question).

Comment: Do you have access to another workibt PC?

Comment: No, but I have friends :) What would I need to do on such an other PC?

Answer (score 0):

Ask a friend to help you do the following:

Download and install [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) (You will need an USB flash drive).

If you want to recover your data, you will need a live CD that you have to create first. I prefer using [this one](http://windowsmatters.com/2015/08/16/windows-10-x64-pe-with-all-x64-apps/), everything is configured and ready to use.

All you have to do is download the ISO, and use Rufus to make a USB flash drive bootable with the ISO.

Than you can use the USB flash drive to boot into your PC. I suggest you try the recovery software included in the Live CD first. Also don't forget to backup your important files.

If the Live CD fails to recover and make your Windows bootable, you will need to do a fresh install.

Again, you can use Rufus to create a bootable USB flash drive from any ISO file.

For a free solution, you can download and use Ubuntu.

You can also download and install Windows as well using this method.